# Can't find the classes of an external jar imported in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I created a new project in Eclipse in which I want to use the JTS library.
I imported the library during the creation of the project but I can't find the classes in the package explorer.

Since I am not experienced in Java and Eclipse, I'll explain what I did from the start.

1. I download the JTS library from GitHub: https://github.com/locationtech/jts
2. I create jts-core.jar using `jar` in the command line. I place it in workspace/Libraries
3. In Eclipse I create a new project in workspace/Projects/JTS-test. In the "build settings" I go to "Libraries" and "Add external JARs..." and select my jar.
4. This is what my package explorer in Eclipse looks like after step 3 :

[image: Package Explorer]

However, when I browse in jts-core.jar outside Eclipse, org/locationtech/jts/algorithm/ is full of .java files and contains directories themselves containing other .java files.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Looks like you have issue with jar creation, did you use "jar cvf jts-core.jar *" from you command prompt ?

Comment: I used `jar cf jts-core.jar *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JAR file referenced as a library must contain the `*.class` files (bytecode). In the JAR, the `*.java` files (source code) are only to see the source code and the Javadoc, but are not required.

Before `jar`, you missed compiling the `*.java` files (`javac`). Instead of creating a JAR yourself, you can [download a ZIP file with all required JARs from the release page of the jts project](https://github.com/locationtech/jts/releases). This ZIP file contains also the JARs that are required by jts.

Alternatively, you can copy the `*.java` files into the source folder (`src` by default) of your project or create add a new source folder for these `*.java` files. In contrast to classes in JARs, `*.java` files in source folders can be edited.